# В каком виде лучше хранить системный текст?

Tags: текст

Здравствуйте
Подскажите в каком виде лучше хранить текст ошибок, уведомлений на сайте?

1. в базе данных
2. в переменной в виде массива
3. в отдельном классе, в виде констант
4. в ini файле

текста не так и много конечно, но по мере развития сайта, количество будет расти, вот и хочу пред угадать сейчас, чтоб не гадать потом.

или может подскажите собственный вариант, как это реализовано в Ваших проектах.

Comment: Лично на моём сайте вариант 2 и 3. Коды ошибок в константах, текст ошибки - в массиве. Но тут стоит учитывать есть ли у вашего сайта поддержка различных языков

Answer (score 0):

1. ***в переменной в виде массива*** Плохо, это php, если это массив представьте что вы получаете всегда только 1 ошибку, ***а в память пхп загрузятся все возможные строки ошибок.***
2. ***Ini файл, плохо.*** Этоже ini, тоесть прогрузка практически 99% не нужной инфы в оперативку.
3. ***в отдельном классе, в виде констант.*** Это повторение пункта 1-2. Даже если обгородить условиями, скорость низкая.
4. ***в базе данных.*** Конечно вариант получше файла, но вечно нагружать базу данных ради вывода ошибок..

Лично сам не знаю что использовать...

Подкину как пример для ошибок с исключениями. Это хорошо подходит для исключений, + сам язык можно указать в инклуд функции.

```
<?php

#Ulin Project 2017

spl_autoload_register(
    function ($n) {
        $arr = explode('\\', $n, 2);

        if(isset($arr[0])){
            if(isset($arr[1])){
                if($arr[0] == 'err'){
                    include '/home/www/html/DELETE2/ru/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $arr[1]).'.php';
                }
            }
        }
    }
);


try{
    throw new err\newMessage('Привет как дела...'); 
    # в лс используются не правильные символы шли искл

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Ошибка:'.$e->text;
}
```

Директория /ru/newMessage.php

```
<?php

namespace err;
use Exception;

class newMessage extends Exception {
    public $text;

    public function __construct($e){
        $this->text='Не правильное лс:'.$e;

        parent::__construct($this->text);
    }
}
```

Вывод: `Ошибка:Не правильное лс:Привет как дела...`

Comment: Кто-то спер или разместил мою работу на https://pastebin.com/2xb8XmLb